# Access to linux virtual memory

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

In new kernel versions `/dev/kmem` is disabled, is there any other way I can access linux virtual memory? My goal is to search through memory, find function calls and insert kprobes on their addresses.

Comment: Each process has its own address space, so what do you want to do? for process of pid 1234, you could use `/proc/1234/mem`   ...

Answer (score 3):

The idea of having `kmem` disabled is exactly preventing you to do what you want. You could recompile the kernel with `CONFIG_DEVKMEM=Y` to re-enable `/dev/kmem`

Comment: I know that `kmem` is disabled for security reasons, but recompiling kernel isn't the best solution for me. What about LKM? Can I access virtual memory from LKM?